# How to make an outosum and average function in footer of table PHP

Tags: php, html, html-table, sum

I'm trying to display automatically the total sum (also the average for certain rows) of a row in the footer of a PHP table.

I'm not sure how can I do that.

---

I'm using this query:

```
$query =  "SELECT sector, SUM(usdAmount) AS total, SUM(sumaAbas) as abas FROM DatosSpend WHERE negotiableProcGl='Y' GROUP BY sector
```

and populating the table like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          echo '
          <tr>
            <td class="text-center title-row-table">'.$row["sector"].'</td>
              <td class="text-right table-spend">$'.number_format($row["total"]/"1000",0).'</td>
              <td class="text-right table-spend">'.round(@($row["abas"]/$row["total"]*"100"),0).'%</td>';
            }
```

Comment: please write your code for help you !!

Comment: Please provide an example of what you've tried so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks! I added some code